# pip3 not installed in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

After restarting my Datalab instance - I am getting /bin/sh: 1: pip3: not found

when trying to run:
!pip3 install h5py

I have my kernel set to Python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [latest release](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/releases/tag/1.2.20180221), pip for python3 should be available as just "pip" in the Python 3 kernel.

You can verify this by running "!pip --version"